# How to increment slot field when booking an appointment

Tags: python-3.x, django, web

Doctor model

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qualifications = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    expertise = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Cardiac')
    fee = models.IntegerField(default=500)
    slots = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def incSlots(self):
        self.slots = self.slots + 1
```

Appointment model

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blood_pressure = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    BMI = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    blood_sugar = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    HB = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    platelets = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    detail = models.TextField()
    doc = models.OneToOneField(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Appointment view

```
def appointment(request):
    docname = request.POST.get('doc_name')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.doc.incSlots()
            form.save()
            return redirect('success')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    form = AppointmentForm(initial={"patient":request.user, "doc_name": docname})
    return render(request, 'appointment.html', {'form': form})
```

I want to increment "slot" field when booking an appointment, I have no idea how to do it, i am new to django, i'll appreciate any help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `view.py`:

```
import Doctor
    def appointment(request):
        docname = request.POST.get('doc_name')
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                doc = form.cleaned_data['doc']
                print(doc)
                doc = Doctor.objects.get(pk=doc.pk)
                print(doc)
                doc.slots += 1
                doc.save() 
                return redirect('success')
            else:
                print(form.errors)
        form = AppointmentForm(initial={"patient":request.user, "doc_name": docname})
        return render(request, 'appointment.html', {'form': form})
```

Hope this will work, if face any error comment bellow.

Comment: 'AppointmentForm' object has no attribute 'doc', 'AppointmentForm' object has no attribute 'doc'     Its showing this error.

Comment: Doesn't your form have any attribute for the doc? is the doc field empty?

Comment: class AppointmentForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AppointmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['patient'].readonly = True

    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = '__all__'                                                                                               
   This is my AppointmentForm in forms.py

Comment: Check what values you are receiving.